# after setting attribute for HttpSession it becomes Null

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I'm developing a Sign up operation, where the user enter his email and password press the submit(createUser method) button,  User entity get persisted AND set the id of User in HttpSession, next he moved to next jsf where enter information for School Object (Entity). My problem is that the User get persisted BUT the School is not. here is my code:

```
public CreateBn() {
    user = new User();
    school = new School();
    adress = new Adresse();
    school.setAdresse(adress);
    facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
}

public String createUser() {
    initialiserDateInscription();
    session.setAttribute("UserId", user.getId());
    //System.out.println((BigInteger) session.getAttribute("UserId"));
    userPr.createUser(user);
    return SHCOOL_INSCRIPTION;
}

public String createSchool() {
    BigInteger userId = (BigInteger) session.getAttribute("UserId");
    System.out.println("MEHDI : " + userId);
    try {
        User userTemp = userPr.getUserById(userId);// Here is the problem 
        school.setUser(userTemp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    session.setAttribute("SchoolId", school.getId());
    school.setAdresse(adress);
    schoolPr.createSchool(school);
    return INSCRIPTION_RETURN;
}
```

as you can see I get the User entity based on the UserId saved in session, but I get nothing, it says:

```
javax.persistence.NoResultException: getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities.
```

any more info, I'm here. So how can I solve this??

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "school", name = "school")
public class School implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private BigInteger id;

private String name;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private User user;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "adressId")
private Adresse adresse;
```

EJB

```
@Stateless
public class UserPr {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "proj")
private EntityManager em;


public void createUser(User user) throws RuntimeException{
    try {
        em.persist(user);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public User getUserById(BigInteger UserId) throws Exception{
    try{
        return em.createNamedQuery("User.findById", User.class).setParameter("id", UserId).getSingleResult();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="User.findById", query="SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.id = :id")
})
public class User implements Serializable {
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the userPr class as well?

Comment: Also, as i can see in the code that you have posted, when you call the createUser function you dont set anything in the user object. ie you dont call somewhere user.id = id. Maybe, you implement this in some part of the code that i dont see. In the database, is the user object saved correctly?

Comment: the user get persisted in the DB, I see table change. the problem is in setting and getting UserId to & from session. enity user is initialized in the constructor so all I have to do is to persisted

Comment: Can you post the code for the function getUserById?

Comment: The code for the getUserById seems ok. If you debug the application , the UserId that you pass in the function getUserById, is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the way you get and set the userId.

instead of this line

```
session.setAttribute("UserId", user.getId());
```

try this

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
sessionMap.put("UserId", user.getId());
```

and instead of this

```
BigInteger userId = (BigInteger) session.getAttribute("UserId");
```

try this

```
BigInteger userId  = (BigInteger) sessionMap.get("UserId");
```

Answer (score 0):

First some remarks about the mode: I don't think School should have a OneToOne relationship with User. More likely it is a OneToMany relationship. And maybe you don't want to have a separate Entity for Adresse, it could probably be an Embeddable instead.

How is your persistence set up? How are you managing transactions? The problem you see might be caused by transactional boundaries. How are the createUser and createSchool methods called exactly?

Comment: I just start developing it, of course I will modify. my problem is in setting & getting session attributes. method are called from JSF buttons